# How to merge notifications to a single notification instance?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to implement notification feature for my app. It sends an `OrderReceived` notification to the courier every time an `Order` is created via `OrderObserver`.

The current implementation works fine but there is a problem. When multiple user ordered an item at the same time (let's say 100), the courier will receive 100 notifications which is not good.

I am wondering if there is any way to merge these notifications to a single notification instance so instead of sending this message 100 times:

> Order Received!

It should send this notification instead:

> 100 Orders Received!

I'm thinking about using queues to achieve this, but as I read the docs and try to understand, by queueing it, it will produce the same behavior since it queues 100 instances of the notification.

Here is my implementation. What can I do to accomplish this?

`OrderObserver.php`

```php
class OrderObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Order "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Order  $order
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Order $order)
    {
        User::couriers()->each(function ($courier) use ($order) {
            $courier->notify(new OrderReceived($order));
        });
    }
}
```

`OrderReceived.php`

```php
class OrderReceived extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * The received order.
     * 
     * @var Order
     */
    protected Order $order;

    /**
     * The title of this notification.
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $title;

    /**
     * The subtitle of this notification.
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $subtitle;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->title = 'Pesanan Diterima!';
        $this->subtitle = 'Ada pesanan baru nih! Yuk cek dimana~';
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [FcmChannel::class];
    }

    public function toFcm($notifiable)
    {
        return FcmMessage::create()
            ->setData(['order_id' => $this->order->id])
            ->setNotification(
                \NotificationChannels\Fcm\Resources\Notification::create()
                    ->setTitle($this->title)
                    ->setBody($this->subtitle)
            )
            ->setAndroid(
                AndroidConfig::create()
                    ->setFcmOptions(AndroidFcmOptions::create()->setAnalyticsLabel('analytics'))
                    ->setNotification(AndroidNotification::create()->setColor('#0A0A0A'))
            )->setApns(
                ApnsConfig::create()
                    ->setFcmOptions(ApnsFcmOptions::create()->setAnalyticsLabel('analytics_ios'))
            );
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
            ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
            ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I decided that this behavior should be handled on the client side using the `FCM` notification API by setting a `collapse_key` on Android and `apns-collapse-id` on iOS in my `OrderReceived` notification class so it will collapse when notifications with the same key pops out.

And treat the current behavior as a limitation until I found better solution.

```php
/**
 * This enum is stored in another part of the application
 * 
 * Maximum allowed collapse key in android is 4 so we need
 * to create an enum to track how many collapse keys do we
 * have in our app.
 *
 * @see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidconf
 *
*/
enum CollapseKeys: string
{
  case orderReceived = 'orderReceived';
}


// inside `toFcm` method of `OrderReceived.php`

protected string $collapseKey = CollapseKeys::orderReceived->value;

// android
AndroidConfig::create()->setCollapseKey($this->collapseKey)

// ios
ApnsConfig::create()->setHeaders([
    'apns-collapse-id' => $this->collapseKey
])
```

Feel free if you guys have any other approach that could possibly implemented on server side.

I would be very happy.